# is it a correct sentence "there itself I given our comments"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

**situation:**
I visited a factory and next day updating my boss my visit.

**verbal Explanation on next day**
I visited their factory yesterday. they shown the HMI simulation. there itself ( to mean during the demo of HMI itself) I given my comments on the visualization of HMI was not looking good.

**Query**
My explanation, is it conveying proper meaning? 
"there itself" is it right sentence? is it used by the native?

Comment: Your sentence is not grammatical at all. Not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you, I can understand that but this is how I am framing most of my sentence. may be I am not thinking in English. Could you please mention specific part which is more confusing?

Comment: @Aayvu.com Do you mean "While they were running the simulation"? I think you are trying to translate a certain phrase from your language word-for-word and coming up with "there itself", but this is not English. I'm making a wild guess that that phrase of yours means ["Right then and there"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/then--and--there) (click on this link and look at #12).

Comment: @tenebris2020, yes. your guess was right. On the spot during the demo I have given my comments is what I want to convey. instead of "there itself" Can I replace "right there during that demo itself i given my comments"?

Comment: *I visited their factory yesterday. They **showed** me the HMI simulation **then and there*** (not "there itself").

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Thank you. Rest of my sentence was OK?

Comment: @Aayvu.com "I gave", not "I given".

Comment: Interestingly, the collocation [then and there](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=then+and+there%2Cthere+and+then&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthen%20and%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20and%20then%3B%2Cc0) was *way* more common than [there and then](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=then+and+there%2Cthere+and+then&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthen%20and%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20and%20then%3B%2Cc0) a century ago. A preference since reversed in BrE, but not AmE

Comment: @Aayvu.com: Don't push it! :) Proofreading is Off Topic, but I gave you the benefit of the doubt by assuming you were specifically looking for an idiomatic way of expressing what you meant by "there itself".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry for that. But actually my intention was not to get proofread. thought of getting comments on rest of the sentence was also reads like native language to English translation. I understand that it is not question any specific.

Comment: @Aayvu.com: If you have several things you're not sure about, it's quite okay to ask several separate questions. But please, *each time you ask about something*, tell us (using lots of words, if necessary) exactly what you *mean*. And if you think you know a way to say it, but you're not sure, explain *why* you think your version might not be correct.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for the idea. I will follow it.

Comment: @tenebris2020 thanks for correction. I always have a confusion of given or gave to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very common idiomatic usage for OP's context would be...

> *I visited their factory yesterday. They showed me the HMI simulation **then and there**.*

Note that [*as a Brit*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=then+and+there%2Cthere+and+then&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthen%20and%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20and%20then%3B%2Cc0) I was initially going to write ***there and then***. But because I knew both sequences were in use, I checked [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=then+and+there%2Cthere+and+then&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthen%20and%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20and%20then%3B%2Cc0), which clearly shows that ***then and there*** is and always has been far more common overall.

So it turns out that there's a significant US/UK usage split here, but I doubt many people on either side of the pond would know that, or think there was anything unusual if they encountered the sequence that's less common among their fellow countrymen.

---

I should also add that in most contexts where the expression would be used, ***where*** implies ***when*** and ***when*** implies ***where*** (since the "referent" is usually a specific time *and* place). Using *both* is thus a device to add emphasis, which is often amplified even more with [***right*** there and then](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=a_91Wq7HHciYgAbIoai4Bg&q=%22right%20there%20and%20then%22&oq=%22right%20there%20and%20then%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...403154.404527.0.405547.6.6.0.0.0.0.128.501.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.2RTt9Ex0WpM) (About 160,000 results) or [***right*** then and there](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=Xv91WrDROemYgAbX7qbQCw&q=%22right%20then%20and%20there%22&oq=%22right%20then%20and%20there%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...659954.661413.0.662255.6.6.0.0.0.0.137.546.4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.wr6HmnW5-iA) (About 27,300,000 results!).

It's interesting to speculate why Brits in particular should have decided about 50 years ago that ***there*** should come before ***then*** (and by implication, be more contextually important), even though [they also had the opposite preference a century ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=then%20and%20there%2Cthere%20and%20then&year_start=1800&year_end=1900&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthen%20and%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20and%20then%3B%2Cc0).